# Can't deploy Spring JAX-WS services

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am working on spring project and I want to deploy my web services  using JAX-WS . I have specified the necessary jars in my pom.xml includings the spring jars, JAX-WS jars and spring-JAxws plugin .

but when I compile I get these errors :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/databinding/MetadataReader;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/databinding/MetadataReader;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/databinding/MetadataReader;)Z
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:352) ~[jaxws-spring-1.9.jar:na]
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:80) ~[jaxws-spring-1.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

and this happens only when I include web services beans declaration in my ApplicationContext.xml file . here's it's XML code : 
[image]

Do you have any idea about how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Check your dependencies.  I was receiving the same error as you when I was utilizing version 2.2.7 of jaxws-rt.  Upping the version to 2.2.8 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This exception tells you that deployment process didn't find some jaxws (from sun) object. Because jaxws is part of JRE (from 1.5 or 1.6) then we must suppose that you use incorrect version. Check if your appserver has compatible version of Java EE and JAX-WS RI:

Example:
Glassfish 3.1.2 on Java 6 build 3+ (EE 5) needs jaxws-ri 2.1 (i.e.: if you're using jaxws-spring packaging then use version 1.8)

[More about jaxws shipping version and Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292804/cant-deploy-spring-jax-ws-services)